# Human insensitive video compression

Tags: compression, libav

I have an AVI video file recorded by my laptop web-cam. It's only 10 minutes but it has so large size, 3.9 GB! I'm not expert in multimedia but I've seen really good quality long movies in only 4 GB. So, I think this file size is not rational for only a 10 minutes video.

For days, I'm trying to re-encode this video to decrease it's size **with no human sensitive changes in it's audio/video quality** (because it's an important family video). But, I could not find any helpful material on Internet about this. I just tried **avconv** on Ubuntu Linux but every time I get errors which I am not familiar with them.

The current audio/video codecs are: (reported by **avconv**)

```
  Duration: 00:10:47.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 48489 kb/s
Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 640x480, 32.99 tbr, 32.99 tbn, 32.99 tbc
Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

I have several files like above which I would like to write them down to a few DVDs. I am not familiar with audio/video codecs and formats. Could you please help me how I can do this, again I bold **with no human sensitive changes in it's quality**? i.e. like normal movies quality on a DVD.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an application for authoring a DVD video. Here is a list of [DVD authoring applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DVD_authoring_applications). I have personally used both Pinnacle and Adobe Premiere Elements, and got good results. If the material is in higher definition, you could consider using Blu-ray instead.

I would, though, recommend to save the raw video for later. Back them up on external hard drives, or something.

Comment: Thanks alot,yes,I'll back them up on ex-hard. however, I'd like to do also on DVD but I do not like a lot of DVDs for only a few minutes and also my laptop does not support blue-ray. Do these apps compress the video too as I mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, they create a DVD video, not a DVD data. The video is encoded in MPEG-2. You could fit  several hours in one DVD, but then the quality would not be to good. I guess between one and two hours per DVD is quite satisfactory.

Comment: If you prefer to create a DVD with data content, you could use a free application to convert the video to for example MP4: [Miro](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/)

Comment: Thanks a tone! I tried `DeVeDe` from your list which fortunately was also present at `Ubuntu Software Center`. It could compress that 3.9GB into only about 130MB mpg file! I opened both side-by-side and could not sense any quality change! Thanks to `DeVeDe`, it rescued my from underlying format and codecs complexity :)